# How to create a new Angular variable on Pug

Tags: angular, pug

Is there a way to assign a new variable to avoid repeating code on pug?

In the simple example below I would like to assign **item.value1 + item.value2** to a new var called "mysum" and use it on the last line as **mysum + item.value3**.

```
tr(*ngFor="let item of list)
    td {{item.value1}}
    td {{item.value2}}
    td {{item.value3}}
    td {{item.value1 + item.value2}}
    td {{item.value1 + item.value2 + item.value3}}
```

Is it possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a typescript method to do that as below,

```
tr(*ngFor="let item of list)
    td {{item.value1}}
    td {{item.value2}}
    td {{item.value3}}
    td {{sumValues(item.value1,item.value2)}}
    td {{mySum + item.value3}}
```

Typescript code

```
sumValues(value1,value2){
    this.mySum = value1 + value2;
    return this.mySum
}
```

Comment: Ok, this works, but if I want another calculation further, now using **mySum+item.value3** to be summed to **item.value4** and so on and inside a loop, so **mySum** couldn't be just one value, but calculated on the fly for each iteration. That's why I'm looking for defining a new variable. Is is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Pug supports variables.

```
- var mysum = {{item.value1}} + {{item.value2}};
- var mysum2 = mysum + {{item.value3}};

tr(*ngFor="let item of list)
  td {{item.value1}}
  td {{item.value2}}
  td {{item.value3}}
  td=mysum
  td=mysum2
```

---

***Alternate syntax***

```
td #{mysum}
td #{mysum2}
```

Comment: These variables are on pug scope and does not access data from angular. Sorry didn't explain the origin of the data.